# @PreAuthorize is not invoked

Tags: java, spring-security

I configured my `security.xml` file to support `preAuthorized` annotations

```
<bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="package.MyPermissionEvaluatorClass" />

<bean id="expressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator" />
</bean>

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>
```

I added `proxy-target-class=true` as my REST class

My REST method with annotation looks like this

```
@PreAuthorize("@permissionEvaluator.hasPermission(#organizationId, 'MY_PERMISSION')")
@RequestMapping()
public ModelAndView findProductConfigurationsByOrganizationId(...) {}
```

My permissions evaluation class looks like this

```
public class MyPermissionEvaluatorClass extends PermissionEvaluatorImpl {

@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication userObj, Object target, Object permission) {
    LOGGER.info("Attempt to resolve permissions for {}.", target);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication userObj, Serializable target, String targetType,
        Object permission) {
    return false;
}
```

But when I do rest requests - it seems does not enter method `hasPermission` at all.

What is the problem?

Comment: AOP is only applied in the same application context. Your `security.xml` is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and the security applies there. Not the beans loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. Include the `global-method-security` in that context as well.

Comment: You mean add it to `xml` with beans?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.